# Difference between Collections.synchronizedMap() and synchronized

Tags: java, collections, synchronized

if i create map

```
Map map=new HashMap(40,.75f);
```

synchronizing it in following two different ways

```
Collections.synchronizedMap(map) :- which is internally using mutex
synchronized(map){}
```

what is the difference between the two above approaches.

Comment: Is this Java? If so, maybe add a language tag

Answer (score 1):

```
Collections.synchronizedMap(map) :- which is internally using mutex
synchronized(map){}
```

> what is the difference between the two above approaches.

The difference is that `Collections.synchronizedMap(map)` is doing the synchronization for you by wrapping the map in a synchronized object.  If you look at the Java source for `Collections` class, you should see the `SynchronizedMap` object.  In there it does stuff like:

```
final Object      mutex;        // Object on which to synchronize
...
public int size() {
   synchronized (mutex) {return m.size();}
}
```

So internally it is doing the same as you calling `synchronized` externally.  However, it takes the guess work and programming of you doing it manually.  It saves you from missing and not protecting an important method call or passing your `Map` to another library that doesn't properly synchronize it or something.

There is a 3rd option that may be better which is to use the `ConcurrentHashMap`.  That is a hash-map which is written from scratch to allow multiple threads to operate on it in parallel.  It will provide better performance than the two options you mention.

Answer (score 0):

A synchronized object assure that only one thread at a time can use the object.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

Comment: but i dont understand if i use synchronized(map) only one thread can access it.then why it is being used Collections.synchronized(map).this i am not understanding,i want to know both will work same or differently

Comment: `Collections.synchroinzedMap(map)` is a shortcut for `synchronized(map){}`. They act the same.